# How do I fix my keyboard?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I run Ubuntu on a Compaq Presario CQ60 laptop. I recently switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.04. After updating, my laptop keyboard no longer works. I suspect that it may have deleted the driver for the keyboard, but I don't really know much about it or even how I would download a new driver (if that is what it is). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does it work in a live session?

Comment: I'm not sure what a live session is.

Comment: A live session is what you boot with Ubuntu installation media, USB stick or DVD.

Comment: Sorry if I seem completely oblivious to what you are talking about, I kinda am. I used the software updates application to update to 17.04.

Comment: Didn't you installed Ubuntu before? That you most likely did in a live session. If you never installed Ubuntu then ask the person who installed for you.